# batch script to turn off monitor?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've tested these two commands on Win-7 :

```
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
```

They've successfully turned off my monitor. I know they are the same but which one is better and compatible with all Windows editions? will this script work fine on Win 10 and without asking for admin right ?

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows 10 22H2. It sets the monitor timeout to "Never".

Answer (score 2):

From Help (powercfg /?)

They are **identical**. `-X` is for people too lazy to type `-change`.

> ```
>   -CHANGE, -X Modifies a setting value in the current power scheme.
>
>               Usage: POWERCFG -X <SETTING> <VALUE>
>
>               <SETTING>   Specifies one of the following options:
>                           -monitor-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                           -monitor-timeout-dc <minutes>
>                           -disk-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                           -disk-timeout-dc <minutes>
>                           -standby-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                           -standby-timeout-dc <minutes>
>                           -hibernate-timeout-ac <minutes>
>                           -hibernate-timeout-dc <minutes>
>
>               Example:
>                   POWERCFG -Change -monitor-timeout-ac 5
>
>               This would set the monitor idle timeout value to 5 minutes
>               when on AC power.
> ```

Comment: will this work on Win-10 please ? I need to know because I don't have win 10 to test it

does dc means laptop is not on ac power ?

Comment: Yes that is what DC means.

Answer (score 1):

From **Windows 10**'s cmd line, I run `powercfg /?`

> /CHANGE, /X        Modifies a setting value in the current power scheme.

Both `/X` and `/CHANGE` are valid switches and seeing as I ran this is on **Windows 10** it means it will work.

Also, though using `-` as a valid switch activator, you can also use `/` which is a windows default:

```
powercfg.exe /change /monitor-timeout-ac 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::PostMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

save this as bat file. (ef offmonitors.bat)
turns off all screens. (run with admin rights)