# How to Shut Off Screen with BAT Script that Actually Closes Itself Afterwards

Tags: batch-file

I found this script to shut off my computer screen:

```
powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

In addition to this script being problematic in that it doesn't automatically close, & prevents f.lux from working before I close the console upon moving my cursor to turn my screen back on, I find the fact that this script needs to use Windows PowerShell seems like overkill.

So, this may be a stupid request, but I'm hoping someone knows a way to run a batch script without the use of PowerShell that turns off the screen & automatically closes.

Edit:

Here are some of the commands I've tried (and their results):

This command (with any combination of `-NoLogo`, `-NoProfile`, and `-Command` either at the end or not) shuts off the screen, but causes a blank powershell window to stay open:

```
start powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

This command (with or without the specific reference to powershell.exe, with or without the empty quotation marks before it, with or without an `@` symbol before `start`, & with any combination of `-NoLogo`, `-NoProfile`, and `-Command` either at the end or not) doesn't shut off the screen, and causes the powershell window below (which only stays open due to my `-NoExit` command):

```
start "" "%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)"
```

The only thing that changes with the entering of that command is the temporary file referenced in this powershell window:
[image]

Comment: [batch script to turn off monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48979552/1417694)

Comment: If you don't want the cmd.exe window to stay open whilst Powershell is running the command, use `Start`. Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?`, to read its usage information.

Comment: @Compo While that does work, it creates another problem by causing a powershell window to open that stays open.

Comment: @Squashman @Compo Neither `powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0`, nor `powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-ac 0` cause my computer monitor to shut off. Even when I run those commands in a Command Prompt with elevated permissions. Please reopen my question before proposing a solution that you assume works without even checking with me first.

Comment: I would generally use, `@Start "" "%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Your command between these doublequotes"`. I'd possibly even consider, _depending upon the task_, using the `-NonInteractive` and/or `-WindowStyle Hidden` options, _before `-Command`_. BTW, you asked for "a way to run a batch script without the use of PoweShell that turns off the screen & automatically closes", that's what the duplicate link answers. Whether you can make that work for you does not change the fact that it's a duplicate question.

Comment: @Compo Well that's frustrating. I tried that & it popped up a Windows PowerShell window with a bunch of red text that I could barely see (let alone read) before it closed. You would think removing at least one combination of `-NoLogo` and `-NoProfile` would at least cause that window to wait for user input to close, but I guess Windows command line must be designed to be as counterintuitive as possible.

Comment: @LoganKling, my apologies.  I didn't test it.  I normally just look for a duplicate question on the site first.  When I saw that Gerhard had responded and it had upvotes, I assumed it worked.

Comment: @Squashman No worries. I was more annoyed with Compo's hastiness (& then pedantry) anyways. I'm sure it worked for those people, two years ago, but Windows changes a lot (especially recently with the way Windows 10 recieves updates).

Comment: That's all you are expected to do @Squashman, we don't need to test answers which have been upvoted and accepted, when selecting them as duplicates. I've reopened your question, Logan. Can you please try to investigate why a Powershell window is opening? I've **never** had one do so when running powershell.exe from a batch file.

Comment: @Compo Thanks! I'll do that & add it to my question, as a summary of my results so far is already too much for a comment, but this will take some time.

Comment: Okay, I have posted what I would assume to work based upon that

Comment: @LoganKling, I did test the code yesterday and it didn't immediately take affect.  But when I booted my computer this morning, it started working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that the command you found was not doublequoted and therefore required an escape character, `^`, to function. Based upon my previous advice, of enclosing the command within doublequotes, the following is my suggestion, *i.e. removing the caret*:

```batch-file
@Start "" "%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,int hMsg,int wParam,int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves the blank PowerShell window open. I upvoted your answer for putting in the effort to find the answer to this question, but I have to wonder: does this command really not leave a PowerShell window open on your PC if you run it?

Comment: As I've already stated, a Powershell console should not be opening, you're running a batch file, not a Powershell script. My assumption is that either you have configured batch files to run in a different application, _(although I have no idea how that should change the behavior)_, or that the C# code, is returning a result, possibly an ErrorLevel to PowerShell, instead of the true initiating application. If I get some time to access a Windows 10 computer later, I'll take a look. I've just tried exactly what you posted in `cmd.exe` and my answer from a batch file in Windows 7, and both worked!

Comment: After months my dumbass self finally figured out the issue. I was running this command in an already open command prompt window.