# Batchfile execute only when an RDP session is active

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, rdp

Background:

I have stuff running automatically on my machine that does not work properly when an RDP session is active (it's because of different screen resolutions), and also not when the local machine is locked.

However, I (and several other people) are regularly working on that machine via RDP, but we are prone to forget to close the RDP session, so I created a scheduled task that runs when the PC enters idle mode that closes the RDP session and unlocks the local machine again.

The next problem was: The batch file also runs when there is no RDP connection active.
Using the power of google I found a way of making the batchfile at least quit immediately when the user is only logged in locally.

This is what my batch currently looks like

```
for /f "tokens=2,4" %%a in ('QUERY USER ^| FINDSTR ">"') DO (

    set "consoleTemp=%%a"
    set "connectionState=%%b"
    set "consoleType=!consoleTemp:~0,7!"

)

SET consoleTypeCorrect=

IF "!consoleType!"=="console" goto closebatch
@echo =================================================
@echo ===  Remote session is closing in ONE MINUTE  ===
@echo =================================================
timeout /t 60 /nobreak
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
Endlocal
Exit

:closebatch
Endlocal
EXIT
```

The settings for the scheduled task above are like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk7iB.jpg

Now, this creates another problem: the monitor of the pc stays on, because every time the pc goes idle, the task is run, the batch is executed, which apparently prevents the monitor to go to "sleep".
I have also tried to disable the setting "wake the computer to run this task, but it doesn't change this behavior.

so my main question is: How can I prevent the monitor to remain active when this task is run? or is there an even easier way to achieve the whole thing I want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

This might work...but i've not tested it. At least it may help or give you some ideas.

The section for turning the screen off was taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60499680/3004628

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Get local computer SESSIONS info. If find disconnected RDP session, log it off.
:: %%a:SESSIONNAME  %%b:USERNAME   %%c:SESSIONID   %%d:SESSIONSTATE
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in ('QUERY session') DO (
    set "sessionName=%%a"
    set "sessionName=!sessionName:>=!"
    if "!sessionName:~0,3!"=="rdp" do (
        if /I "%%d"=="Active" do (
            set "activeUsers=!activeUsers!%%b, "
        ) else (
            echo Logging of User:%%b
            logoff %%c
            timeout /t 5 /NOBREAK>
        )
    ) else (
        if /I "!sessionName!"=="console" do (
            set "consoleID=%%c"
        )
    )
)

:: If an active console user was detected send a message to their screen.
if defined consoleID (
    if defined activeUsers (
        msg %consoleID% /W The RDP users "!activeUsers:~0,-2!" are still active. All other RDP sessions have been closed.
    ) else (
        msg %consoleID% /W All other RDP sessions have been closed.
    )
)

:: If no active console user detected, run command to turn screen off.
if not defined consoleID (
    @Start "" "%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,int hMsg,int wParam,int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Hi, Sadly this batch does not even disconnect the RDP to begin with, so I cannot say whether the lock screen thing works or not

Comment: To test what is going on, remove the `@echo off` line, then in your scheduled task where you point to this batch file, add ` >>%temp%\RDPsessionCloseLog.txt` onto the end. This should still run the batch file, but output all commands and errors to the log file for checking what does not work.